# Tomcat -Hudson- Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env' in SerialContext in Unit tests

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, tomcat7, jakarta-mail

I'm using Tomcat and Hudson to run JUnit tests and i have a problem with testing the email sending. Running the test on Hudson i got the following error:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env' in SerialContext 
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.getComponentId(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:773)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:655)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:156)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:428)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at com.mycompany.extmon.authentication.ChangePasswordForm.<init>(ChangePasswordForm.java:43)
    at com.mycompany.extmon.authentication.ChangePasswordFormTest.changePasswordTestMissingUser(ChangePasswordFormTest.java:42).
```

I dont get it why does it drops this Glassfish related exception because I'm using tomcat this way:

```
    Context initCtx;
    Context envCtx;
    Session mailSession;

    public ChangePasswordForm() throws NamingException {
        initCtx = new InitialContext();
        envCtx = (Context) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env");
        mailSession = (Session) envCtx.lookup("mail/erik.csik.ext@mycomoany.com");
```

Everything works fine on the live build ,no error, email is sent,but it fails on the unit tests. What did i forgot to set or where should i look for the problem? I have found nothing useful so far. I guess it is something with the Hudson config but I cant find where might the problem be.

Included context.xml part:

```
<Resource name="mail/erik.csik.ext@mycompany.com" auth="Container"
            type="javax.mail.Session"
        mail.smtp.auth="true"
                mail.smtp.host="mail.mycompany.net"
        mail.smtp.port="25"
        mail.smtp.user="admin"
        mail.transport.protocol="smtp"
        password="password"
        mail.smtp.from="erik.csik.ext@mycompany.com"/>
```

Comment: What does your `<Resource..../>` look like?

Comment: @Qben I updated the question to include it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a typo in your lookup:

```
<Resource name="mail/erik.csik.ext@mycompany.com"
```

vs.

```
envCtx.lookup("mail/erik.csik.ext@mycomoany.com");
.......................................^
```

Comment: Yeah i changed this part in the question and the typo not exists in the real code